# Updating Google Chrome Extensions

Tags: google-chrome, browser-addons

Do extensions on Google Chrome update automatically? I am looking all over the place for some sort of a "check for updates" button on all of my extensions but am not finding it.

Comment: As both Sathya and ChrisF mentioned, extensions, as well as Chrome, update automatically. There's a button to update all extensions manually because they aren't updated whenever an update appears, but most likely on a fixed schedule. The button is there only to force an update faster. So, basically, you have nothing to worry about when it comes to extensions, they auto-update almost as soon as they need to be.

Comment: Why on earth would you want *anything* to auto-update? In my experience, this is a horrible idea because *very often*, you will eventually run into an update that besides just fixing bugs or patching security problems, makes drastic changes; frequently, **undesirable** changes. If you auto-update, then you are stuck with the horrible new version, especially when it comes to things like Chrome Extensions where, unlike everything else, Google magically refuses to keep backups of old versions, so you end up with *no choice* but to use the new version. Manual updates are safest.

Comment: @Synetech Welcome to the world of "The Cloud" :|

Comment: Argh! I have been raging against this particular machine since it was still just a twinkle in Microsoft’s eye. Back in the late 90’s when Microsoft did one of their campus <s>advertising trips</s> student-relation tours to our university, one of the reps happened to mention that Microsoft was tinkering with the concept of [SaaS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_as_a_service). I immediately hated it because I could actually see through the shiny, sparkly features to the countless annoyances and problems with it. This is also why I hate Steam. ಠ_ಠ

Comment: For the record, Chrome already auto-updates extensions now and then ([apparently every few hours](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/autoupdate.html#overview)). Because of this, [a *lot* of people](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/screen-capture-by-google/cpngackimfmofbokmjmljamhdncknpmg/reviews) learned the hard way what I was warning above.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Chrome extensions do auto-update. If you want to force-check for updates, look at ChrisF's answer.

Comment: I suspected that given that Chrome itself silently auto-updates, but I wasn't 100% sure.

Comment: @ChrisF I wouldn't have known if I hadn't installed AutoPager extension - it pops open a new tab and navigates to change log everytime the extension gets updated - but hey I never asked to update it!

Comment: @Chris lastpass also warns of new updates.

Answer (score 11):

To force an update go to `chrome://extensions/` (Tools > Extensions) then click on "Developer Mode"

An <kbd>Update Extensions Now</kbd> button appears.

Click it.

Comment: does that mean they don't update otherwise? Its a little odd that updating an extension is an option only developers may be interested in.

Comment: @segfault - see Sathya's answer.

Comment: we're looping here :). See Sathya's answer, see ChrisF's answer.