# Way to check which of the installed Chrome Extensions are not currently up to date?

Tags: google-chrome-extensions

Now, I know Chrome auto updates extensions at some periodic intervals and there is a [manual way to force Extension Updates](https://superuser.com/a/110185) that I use extensively.
[Updating Google Chrome Extensions](https://superuser.com/questions/110184/updating-google-chrome-extensions)

As is right now, there are still several extensions that have not updated to the latest version available in Chrome Store.

Even this only tells me when certain extensions are updated, but does not tell me which extensions are out of date / not up to date.
[How can I tell when Chrome extensions are updated?](https://superuser.com/questions/906711/how-can-i-tell-when-chrome-extensions-are-updated)

In what way could easily check which updates are out of date?

- Any automated/ semi-automated / scripted way is also definitely welcome.

PS: I am running the latest updated version of Chome.